# stored procedure functions not working properly?

Tags: stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, stored-functions

i am writing a procedure function in phpmyadmin for attendance purpose.But i am getting wrong information from function if condition.

below is the sample code for procedure and functions without if.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `USP_GetEmployeeAttendanceReport`(IN selectedIndex int,IN searchText nvarchar(20),IN selectedDate datetime)
BEGIN
select FN_CheckEmpAttendanceStatus(selectedIndex,selectedDate);
END
```

Function FN_CheckEmpAttendanceStatus

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `FN_CheckEmpAttendanceStatus`(cardid varchar(150),selectedDate datetime) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
DECLARE result INT;
set result=(select count(*) from iotrans where CARDID=cardid and dt=selectedDate);
return result;
END
```

but from function i am getting garbage values (i.e 80,0,81,82....).thanks in advance

Comment: Looking at your questions' history I'd **strongly** recommend that you familiarize yourself with the concept of **[upvoting/accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** answers. Otherwise SO members will stop helping you since you don't show appreciation for their time and effort helping you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely caused by the fact that you use **the same name** `cardid` for a function parameter as for a column in `iotrans`,  thus MySQL can't tell them apart and condition `WHERE CARDID=cardid` **always** evaluates as `TRUE`.

Always give distinct names to routine parameters. I'd suggest to come up with some naming scheme, e.g. putting a underscore in front of the name of a parameter, so that you do that consistently across all your code and can easily tell whether it's a parameter or a column name.

One more thing usage of `result` variable is unnecessary overhead in your case as is `BEGIN...END` block.

That being said your function might've looked like this

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
  FUNCTION FN_CheckEmpAttendanceStatus
(
  _cardid varchar(150),
  _selectedDate datetime
) RETURNS INT(11)
RETURN 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM iotrans 
   WHERE cardid = _cardid 
     AND dt = _selectedDate
);
```

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?